# Не записываются значения из dataGridView в созданный List

Tags: c#, datagridview

[image: Создал List и цыкл чтобы из dataGrid только по вертикали записало в list - но не могу исбавиться от ошибок, сделал уже 2 версии кода]

1)

```cs
List <double> listOfTrad = new List<double>();
    for (int a = 0; a < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; a++)
    {
        listOfTrad.Add((double)dataGridView1[1, a].Value);
    }
```

2. 

```cs
List<int> listOfTrad = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
        listOfTrad[i] = (int)dataGridView1[0, i].Value;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов это использовать класс `Convert`. Например:

```
var _listOfTrad = new List<Double>();

for (int a = 0; a < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; a++)
{
     _listOfTrad.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[0, a].Value));
}
```

Второй вариант заключается в хранении строк вместо чисел. Например:

```
var _listOfTrad = new List<string>();

for (int a = 0; a < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; a++)
{
     _listOfTrad.Add((string)dataGridView1[0, a].Value);
}
```

Значение `Value` DGV имеет тип `object`, а вводимые данные имеют строковый тип и упаковываются в этот `object`. Распаковка возможна только в тот тип, который был у переменной до запаковки, поэтому явное приведение к `string` будет работать, а к другим типам нет. Подробнее про распаковку/запаковку можно почитать здесь https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing

Comment: У автора проблема в том, что он берёт значение из последней строки, а там пусто. Вы правильно написали `Count - 1` - вот про это и надо объяснить.

Comment: О, спасибо большое

Comment: Ваш 1 вариант вариант идеально работает, про заспаковку обязательно прочитаю, еще раз спасибо)

Comment: @XARiN если ответ вам подходит, отметьте пожалуйста галочкой